# How do I make the blob have changing color and how do I make the smaller orbiting circles into icons?

Tags: html, css

I need some help in making changes to this blob. https://codepen.io/mcasey/pen/LVoZvg

```
<div class="blobs">  
      <div class="blob"></div>
      <div class="blob"></div>
      <div class="blob"></div>
      <div class="blob"></div>
      <div class="blob"></div>
      <div class="blob"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="blips">
    <div class="blip"></div>
    <div class="blip"></div>
    <div class="blip"></div>
    <div class="blip"></div>
  </div>
```

I am looking to:

1. Make the color of the blob variable and changing
2. I want the orbiting blobs to be icons

Comment: For the first part, you can add `background` directives to your existing animation keyframes. Playing with transparency/opacity might help as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Make the color of the blob variable and changing

Actually, CSS can animate color just like any other parameter. It's pretty good and easy to use.

```
@keyframes mydownleft {
    0%   {left: 0px;top:0px;    transform: rotate(0deg);    background-color: red;}
    50%  {left: 10px; top:10px; transform: rotate(-180deg); background-color: yellow;}
    100% {left: 0px; top:0px;   transform: rotate(-360deg); background-color: red;}
}
```

> 2. I want the orbiting blobs to be icons

I'm not 100% envisioning what you want here but I'm guessing you want them to be images instead of plain `div`s? You should be able to just replace the `div`s with `img`s and just specify a `src` URL. The images might get slightly stretched with your way of ofsetting height so you might actually want to put them inside the divs instead with `overflow:hidden` and some kind of centering CSS perhaps.